# Will exceeding 2000 documents in a SharePoint 2007 Library folder degrade only the performance of that library?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server

I know the work around is to create multiple folders with no more than **2,000** documents in each folder.

I just need to know if every site collection would be effected?

Would it make a difference if the site collection with the **2,000+** files had it's own content database?

Answer (score 1):

2000 is the view threshold. That number of items a view can render.

As the size of Content Database grows performance of these views (with more than 2000) will degrade. You can fine tune this by adding indexes on the fields you are used in the view.

It will be good to split content database i.e. per site collection.

For more on this topic you can refer -

1. http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=188
2. http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-SharePoint_limits.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create more 2000 items in a document library but this limit is for the view, If your view return more than 2000 items then it will put more load on the DB server which cause performance issue.

Even if you create a new site collection in a new content db but still it is on same db server. So when you run a view which return more than 2000 items it give a performance hit on db server which cause performance issue for farm.

other workaround, create index column and use that in view.

[2000 Item Limits for SharePoint Libraries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scaravajal/archive/2007/03/09/2000-item-limits-for-sharepoint-libraries.aspx)

> The following figure shows the difference in throughput between
>   viewing all items in a document library with and without the effective
>   use of folders, which is critical for scaling. As shown in the graph
>   below, throughput performance degrades as the number of documents
>   increases when flat library storage is used. The quickest drop in
>   throughput occurs when the total number of documents is less than
>   2,000, from 151 RPS (at 200 documents) to 63 RPS (at 2,000 documents).
>   At 4,000 documents, throughput decreases to about 13 RPS, or an
>   overall throughput decrease of over 90% from an empty library.

[image]

> The following figure shows the relative performance between folder
>   views when folders are used to store and organize documents, and an
>   indexed view of a flat library structure. Each folder contains 500
>   documents created by different users. In this scenario, there is no
>   significant throughput degradation up to 1 million documents for
>   either scenario, provided that the number of items in the view does
>   not exceed the performance threshold for your system. However,
>   performance is better when folders are used.
>   [image]

Read more here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx